# Server error 500 while trying to instantiate an Amazon s3 client

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting server error 500 while opening my PHP file in a browser.

This is my config.php file:

```
<?php 
return [
    's3' => [
        'key' => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxx',
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
        'bucket' => 'abc.def'
    ]
];
?>
```

The start.php file:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$config = require('config.php');

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'region' => $config['s3Client']['region'],
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $config['s3Client']['key'],
        'secret' => $config['s3Client']['secret'],
    ],
]);
?>
```

I am getting a 500 error when I try to instantiate an Amazon S3 client. I am new to PHP and AWS. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Please enable the error reporting and check what is your error: ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); Put this at the start of PHP file.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you have the right permissions on the designated files you try to read (owner and group)